# Vue app fails to load component on standalone (no error message)

Tags: vue-router

The app works fine on every browser, but when I "Add it to my Home Screen" on my iPad, it loads only the "main" component but none of the children.

Here's my **main.js** :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router'
import App from '@/App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

My **App.vue** :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="bg">BEFORE VIEW</div>
    <router-view class="view"></router-view>
    <div class="bg">AFTER VIEW</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    require('./assets/styles.css')
</script>
```

My **router/index.js** :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Parent from '@/components/Parent'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: __dirname,
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Parent },
    { path: '/products',
      component: Parent
    },
    { path: '/clients',
      component: Parent
    },
    { path: '/verticals',
      component: Parent
    }
  ]
})
```

and the **components/Parent.vue** :

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <p>INSIDE PARENT</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Parent'
  }
</script>
```

Basically this is meant to be a kind of slide show, the Parent component will detect the current Route and go to the appropriate slide.

As I mentionned, the app works very well both on my desktop (on Chrome) and on my iPad (on Safari), but when I do "Add it to my home screen", all I see are the "BEFORE VIEW" and the "AFTER VIEW" from the App.vue (and the #app element has the right background color) but everything in the  just doesn't load.

I feel like an idiot, I'm sure the solution just depends on a tidbit of knowledge I'm missing, but I can't seem to find anyone else with a problem close enough to mine that I can use their solution.

Please help, thank you so much for your time !

Comment: what logic are you using to detect the `route.path` change? `v-if="route.path == '/whateverthepath'"`? typically when referring to `children`, your parent route `/` would have a nested array of children routes...

Comment: Yes, totally, and I did ; for the sake of getting an answer I simplified the contents of **router/index.js**. But yes, normally, each of my "Parent" slides would have had children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly found a solution that makes the desired content appear.
In router/index.js,  I removed the line

```
mode: 'history',
```

I honestly don't understand yet why it worked, but it does. I'll look further.

Thanks to everyone who took a look at my problem !